# WIN API CreateThread not accessible in MFC Share DLL?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

I Make first MFC Apps inside CreateThread Function used but it required 6 parameters. [Create Thread function description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Make MFC Shared DLL all code paste in DLL Application.

but i compile dll then get error

**Error 17 error C2660: 'CWinThread::CreateThread' : function does not take 6 arguments**

how to access create thread function with 6 parameter in mfc share dll app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `CreateThread` function in the global name space:

```
HANDLE thread = ::CreateThread( ... );
```

Comment: Thanks it working. why required global name space in mfc share dll apps. but this not require in mfc apps.

Comment: The error message shows that you were trying to call CreateThread from a member function of a CWinThread. When you do that the compiler assumes you are trying to call the CWinThread function of the same name as the global function.